# Convert QuerySet of Dicts into List of IDs for use in another QS

Tags: python, django

I have a list of "Most Viewed Videos" that is arranged in the following format:

```
class Video(models.Model):
    ....

class Viewcount(models.Model);
    video = models.ForeignKey(Video)
    date = models.DateField
```

I'm trying to generate code to display the "Most Viewed Videos in Past 30 days". This is my code so far:

```
today = datetime.date.today()
thirty_days_ago = today - datetime.timedelta(days=30)
mostviewed = View.objects.filter(date__gte=thirty_days_ago).values('video').order_by('video').annotate(vidcount=Count('video')).order_by('-vidcount')
```

Which outputs:

```
<QuerySet [{'video': 9130}, {'video': 1}, {'video': 9138}, {'video': 9170}, {'video': 3}, {'video': 9135}]>
```

How can I turn this into a simple list for use in a template? Such as:

```
{% for video in new_list %}
{{video}} would output video #9130, then #1, then #9138, etc.
{% endfor %}
```

Basically I want to steal the list of IDs generated by my mostviewed list, and use those to display that list of videos. I'd like the order to be preserved, as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Was able to figure this out on my own. Here's the entire list of code I used to get there:

```
a = View.objects.filter(date__gte=thirty_days_ago).values('video').order_by('video').annotate(vidcount=Count('video')).order_by('-vidcount')
b=[]
for i in a:
    b.append(i['video'])
c = Video.objects.filter(id__in=b)
mostviewed = c.annotate(viewcount=Count('view')).order_by('-viewcount')
```